# How to open new page without refresh in full-screen mode using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullscreen

I want to open a page without refreshing and changing the current mode (full-screen mode) in jQuery, On my page the full-screen is open by default and I would like to redirect users to another page without exiting full-screen and with refreshing.

I use `history.pushState()` but it doesn't work for me.
Here's a small piece of my code

```
<a onclick="history.pushState({},'Another page','./anotherpage?t=abc');" class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange" style="margin-top: 45px; width: 98%;">Next</a>
```

Hope you will understand, please help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<a onclick="openFullscreen()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange" style="margin-top: 45px; width: 98%;">Next</a>

<script>
    function openFullscreen() {
        var win = window.open('https://example.com','full','dependent=yes, fullscreen=yes');
        win.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this is working but not opening in full-screen mode

Comment: Which browser are you using, because this is the standard way which several browsers don't support?

Comment: I'm using  Google Chrome

Comment: Can I use `_self` target init

Comment: Well, as I found out, this feature isn't available anymore due to security reasons. So I think you won't achieve what you want.

Comment: I will research it to be sure and answer you later (about 1 hour)

Comment: Ok i'm waiting for your response, thank you for such interest on my question

Comment: No, it's not working anymore in all major browser. But I noticed, that you wanted to open a page of your own. Is that correct? Because if, it might work.